# Generating recursive structures in scalacheck

Tags: scala, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I'm trying to make a generator for a recursive datatype called `Row`.  A row is a list of named `Val`s, where a `Val` is either an atomic `Bin` or else a nested `Row`.

This is my code:

```
package com.dtci.data.anonymize.parquet

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.scalacheck.Gen

object TestApp extends App {

  sealed trait Val
  case class Bin(bytes: Array[Byte]) extends Val
  object Bin {
    def from_string(str: String): Bin = Bin(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  }
  case class Row(flds: List[(String, Val)]) extends Val

  val gen_bin = Gen.alphaStr.map(Bin.from_string)
  val gen_field_name = Gen.alphaLowerStr
  val gen_field = Gen.zip(gen_field_name, gen_val)
  val gen_row = Gen.nonEmptyListOf(gen_field).map(Row.apply)
  def gen_val: Gen[Val] = Gen.oneOf(gen_bin, gen_row)

  gen_row.sample.get.flds.foreach( fld => println(s"${fld._1} --> ${fld._2}"))
}
```

It crashes with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$flatMap$2(Gen.scala:84)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R.flatMap(Gen.scala:243)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R.flatMap$(Gen.scala:240)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R$$anon$3.flatMap(Gen.scala:228)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Gen.scala:84)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.$anonfun$doApply$1(Gen.scala:110)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.doApply(Gen.scala:109)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$map$1(Gen.scala:79)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$flatMap$2(Gen.scala:84)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R.flatMap(Gen.scala:243)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R.flatMap$(Gen.scala:240)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R$$anon$3.flatMap(Gen.scala:228)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Gen.scala:84)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.$anonfun$doApply$1(Gen.scala:110)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.doApply(Gen.scala:109)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$.$anonfun$sequence$2(Gen.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:168)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:164)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$.$anonfun$sequence$1(Gen.scala:490)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$map$1(Gen.scala:79)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.$anonfun$doApply$1(Gen.scala:110)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.doApply(Gen.scala:109)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$flatMap$2(Gen.scala:84)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R.flatMap(Gen.scala:243)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R.flatMap$(Gen.scala:240)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$R$$anon$3.flatMap(Gen.scala:228)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Gen.scala:84)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$.$anonfun$sized$1(Gen.scala:551)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.$anonfun$doApply$1(Gen.scala:110)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$1.doApply(Gen.scala:109)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.$anonfun$map$1(Gen.scala:79)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$Parameters.useInitialSeed(Gen.scala:318)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$5.doApply(Gen.scala:255)
    at org.scalacheck.Gen.sample(Gen.scala:154)
```

What's wrong with my code, and what would have been the best way for me to diagnose it myself?

As a note, I've seen the remarks about `Gen.oneOf` being strict and needing `Gen.lzy` for recursive structures.  But if, in my code, I wrap the definition of `gen_val` inside of `Gen.lzy(...)` then I get a stack overflow rather than the current null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be careful using `object Main extends App`. I find its fields initialization semantic less obvious than plain old `main` with line-after-line semantics:

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {...}
}
```

This is likely a problem with the `NullPointerException`.

Usually, it can be fixed by careful checking out fields initialization order and marking some (or all of them) `val`'s as `lazy`.

The `StackOverflowError` arises because of too deep generated data structure.

Generally, when you are dealing with any kind of recursion, always consider *the base case* when the recursion should stop and *the step* which eventually will hit the *base case*.

In your particular case we can utilize the `Gen.sized` and `Gen.resize` which are responsible for how "big" are generated elements (checkout docs and google for more information).

```scala
package com.dtci.data.anonymize.parquet

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.scalacheck.Gen

object Main extends App {

  sealed trait Val
  case class Bin(bytes: Array[Byte]) extends Val
  object Bin {
    def from_string(str: String): Bin = Bin(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  }
  case class Row(flds: List[(String, Val)]) extends Val

  val gen_bin = Gen.alphaStr.map(Bin.from_string)
  val gen_field_name = Gen.alphaLowerStr
  val gen_field = Gen.zip(gen_field_name, gen_val)
  val gen_row = Gen.sized(size => Gen.resize(size / 2, Gen.nonEmptyListOf(gen_field).map(Row.apply)))

  def gen_val: Gen[Val] = Gen.sized { size =>
    if (size <= 0) {
      gen_bin
    } else {
      Gen.oneOf(gen_bin, gen_row)
    }
  }

  gen_row.sample.get.flds.foreach(fld => println(s"${fld._1} --> ${fld._2}"))
}
```